# NotReady node with ContainerGCFailed warning

Tags: kubernetes, containers, amazon-eks

see the following in the events:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                   From     Message
  ----     ------             ----                  ----     -------
  Warning  ContainerGCFailed  58s (x1775 over 30h)  kubelet  rpc error: code = ResourceExhausted desc = grpc: trying to send message larger than max (16797216 vs. 16777216)
```

and in Conditions:

```
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  MemoryPressure   False   Sat, 19 Nov 2022 17:17:30 -0600   Wed, 16 Nov 2022 22:28:31 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient memory available
  DiskPressure     False   Sat, 19 Nov 2022 17:17:30 -0600   Wed, 16 Nov 2022 22:28:31 -0600   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk pressure
  PIDPressure      False   Sat, 19 Nov 2022 17:17:30 -0600   Wed, 16 Nov 2022 22:28:31 -0600   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID available
  Ready            False   Sat, 19 Nov 2022 17:17:30 -0600   Fri, 18 Nov 2022 11:03:06 -0600   KubeletNotReady              PLEG is not healthy: pleg was last seen active 30h17m27.791101751s ago; threshold is 3m0s
```

how to interpeter this information? What could be the reason?

Comment: The issue is caused by too many tekton dead pods (over 1700 dead containers), add --`maximum-dead-containers=1000` to the [kubelet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/) command line and restart the kubelet.

Comment: Attaching similar issues [1]- https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/63858, [2]-https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1382

Answer (score 0):

The info is relatively obvious.

> how to interpeter this information?

Kubernetes uses `Garbage collection` to clean up cluster resources. The **`kubelet`** performs garbage collection on unused images every five minutes and on unused containers every minute. Reason "`ContainerGCFailed`" means that it fails the GC process.

> What could be the reason?

The limit Kubelet has set for gRPC messages is 16MB. When you have a LOT of (possibly dead) containers, the size of the gRPC message exceeds it, and kubelet receives the `rpc error`.

**Possible solution:**

Remove those old dead containers and add `--maximum-dead-containers=1000` to the Kubelet to solve the issue.